# Infer the return type of a function within a type and use the return type in the type itself

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I'm writing some types that I will use for a table component in React and are having some issues.

I want to feed the data to the component, and then infer the data type for some different purposes. The problem arises when I introduce a row formatter, which will modify the data and return a new type.

I have greatly simplified the type to illustrate the issue:

```js
type Props<TRow, TFormattedRow> = {
  data: TRow[]
  getRow?: (row: TFormattedRow) => void
  rowFormatter: (row: TRow) => TFormattedRow
}

function createProps<TRow, TFormattedRow>(props: Props<TRow, TFormattedRow>) {
  return props
}
```

When using the `createProps` function by explicitly giving it the type of `row` in `rowFormatter` everything is working correctly - `rowFormatter` infers `formattedRow` correctly as `{ id: string, name: string, count: number }`

```js
createProps({
  data: [
    { id: '1', name: 'Mangus Karlsson', count: 4 },
    { id: '2', name: 'Elsa Nyström', count: 6 },
    { id: '3', name: 'Bengt Blyertz', count: 8 },
  ],
  // getData is infers the formatted row type correctly as { id: string, name: string, count: number }
  getRow: (formattedRow) => console.log(formattedRow),
  rowFormatter: (row: { id: string, name: string, count: number }) => {
    return { id: row.id, idAsNumber: parseInt(row.id) }
  },
})
```

Though, when not explicitly setting the argument of `rowFormatter`, `getRow` infers `formattedRow` as `unknown`:

```js
createProps({
  data: [
    { id: '1', name: 'Mangus Karlsson', count: 4 },
    { id: '2', name: 'Elsa Nyström', count: 6 },
    { id: '3', name: 'Bengt Blyertz', count: 8 },
  ],
  // formattedRow is infered as unknown when not explicitly typing the argument of rowFormatter
  getRow: (formattedRow) => console.log(formattedRow),
  rowFormatter: (row) => {
    return { id: row.id, idAsNumber: parseInt(row.id) }
  },
})
```

Is there a way to solve this without explicitly typing the argument of `rowFormatter`? Or am I missing something fundamental here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you put `rowFormatter` first. ie. the compiler infers the type from that property first.

```
const test = createProps({
  data: [
    { id: '1', name: 'Mangus Karlsson', count: 4 },
    { id: '2', name: 'Elsa Nyström', count: 6 },
    { id: '3', name: 'Bengt Blyertz', count: 8 },
  ],
  rowFormatter: (row) => ({ id: row.id, idAsNumber: parseInt(row.id) }),
  getRow: (formattedRow) => console.log(formattedRow),
})

// inferred type:
// const test: Props<{
//     id: string;
//     name: string;
//     count: number;
// }, {
//     id: string;
//     idAsNumber: number;
// }>
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=6&pln=11&pc=1#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-fGZnN59O3RFQIJK1VwXNx14cUvpuZQYtSOv59FyhXVtWV3u10teRicIA)

---

But depending on your use case, you may be better off explicitly typing the *function call*

```
type MyRow = {id: string, name: string, count: number};
type MyFormattedRow = {id: string, idAsNumber: number};

const test = createProps<MyRow, MyFormattedRow>({
  data: [
    { id: '1', name: 'Mangus Karlsson', count: 4 },
    { id: '2', name: 'Elsa Nyström', count: 6 },
    { id: '3', name: 'Bengt Blyertz', count: 8 },
  ],
  getRow: (formattedRow) => console.log(formattedRow),
  rowFormatter: (row) => ({ id: row.id, idAsNumber: parseInt(row.id) }),
})

// inferred type:
// const test: Props<MyRow, MyFormattedRow>
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZwDwBUBKCDuAaKdAMQTgFsBDYYCAE2xwD4oBeKAbwCgopaqKAXIQYBtALrcoAcwjAGAfiEAKRDiHFSlanQYBKVswBuCAJa1JqkuSo04y1er0HCVrTXq5OAX06cAZgCuAHYAxsAmCEFQIXAQVBDwSGhYuAQa1toeTEpgiChCiSgYDGmuNjq4jLoFecklLprlWcxcPLHAAXBRuUnevqCQUACyIAysHGZCyMBwJkFSBEEUZBBTM3ML0QjBwEJBAWQARhBwXgDcnAPQI2WZY2zsk1DTs-MEZgCCyAByB8d2UH2RxO518IUi0ygNEhbBicRohTQI3qN0ad0qSlavH4QhEkh47CgTwA5ABGYmLZarKDEoYUeYBZBQADSFDgABtkMhIhStjshAAWKBePD4jhE2hCYkAJl5SxWUoAopyKFBviAXgA3si88H8qAANmFop4BIlUoAzHKqVKAEIQebAKC29kgE7AABeuu2QV2UAAHMbJGITdJZAxlH40e4nCxmOCgtz2RAAHTshBSJRRjIx3C6UOWaMnex55yY81QVQpszvWhfX7AgFgNnICAASV9Klw1do+i8+e8ul8AHph0Sgn4TrFaFDwKtOKOtomndC-YjUMjUsMQLdc0xOEA)

I generally prefer explicitly typing things over relying on inference. I would also recommend always explicitly declaring return values of functions. I find it better to *declare your intentions* in order to prevent mistakes in the implementation.

For example, let's say you forgot to parse `idAsNumber` and just did `idAsNumber: row.id`. Your variable now has the `string` type instead of `number`. Typescript won't catch that if you are relying on inference. Now let's say you do `idAsNumber + 1`. Well now you have a string with 1 at the end instead of an incremented id.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and tips!! :)